# Can't debug tomcat application with gradle tomcat plugin

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, gradle

According to [home page](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) of gradle tomcat plugin FAQ section:

> How do I remote debug my Tomcat started up by the plugin?

I need to add the following environment property:

```
GRADLE_OPTS = -Xdebug Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

During run of container I should see information that it listens on particular port: `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`, but in my case it's not working.

How I can configure it properly ? I'm running intellij idea 14.1 Ultimate.

Comment: In intellij are you entering correct values for debugger ?

Comment: @sol4me I configured remote connection somehow but I'm not sure is it working properly, since as I mentioned tomcat plugin does not inform me that it's listening on the port 5005.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it worked as I started the Tomcat in the IDE itself and not the CLI.
For that I created two run/debug configurations, one for Tomcat and one to [Remote](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-remote.html) connect the debugger to the Tomcat process.

For the Remote configuration, use the port 5005 like mentioned in the plugin FAQ debug section.

For the Tomcat configuration, you have to set the JVM settings explicitly. Simply put `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005` as a value into the JVM options textfield in the Gradle run/debug config.

After both configurations have been created and properly configured, first **run** the Tomcat process and then connect to it by **debugging** the Remote configuration.

You can find an entire spring-mvc example and an detailed solution [here](http://kacperbak.github.io/Debugging-a-spring-mvc-web-app-with-the-gradle-tomcat-plugin-and-IntelliJ-IDEA.html).